# A way to automate or speed up transforms on multiple layers in After Effects?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, adobe-after-effects

I am trying to create something i like to call pseudo rotation in space. Given multiple objects created in illustrator, each representing the same thing (e.g. a triangle) of different sizes arranged into a circle (so that some of them seem more distant than the others, I would like to "rotate" them i.e resize and move each of them so that it seems as if they were rotating. I tried doing this the hard way i.e. moving each object manually, which seems to be taking a long time. Is there any way to automate or speed up the process?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the [Parenting](http://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/layer-properties.html#parent_and_child_layers) feature and [Expressions](http://helpx.adobe.com/after-effects/using/expression-basics.html#add_edit_and_remove_expressions).

**Step 1:** Make a null object the parent to your layers, Layers > New > Null Object, by dragging the pick whip to the null object or selecting the null object from the parent drop down on other layers. This allows you to perform transforms on an invisible object for others to mimic.

[image]

**Step 2:** Add an expression to the transform property you wish to link with the null object.

*Example: Click rotation of Layer 1 and from the top menu - Animation > Add Expression.*

[image]

The expression you should use is `parent.transform.rotation`

**That's it:** Now when you change the rotation value of the null object, any layer that the null object is the parent of will also rotate with the same values.